# Sorting a vector of unique pointers using constant iterators

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, unique-ptr, const-iterator

My question is about why I can sort a vector of unique pointers with begin/end but not with cbegin/cend

This compiles:

```
std::sort(teachers.begin(), teachers.end(), compare_by_uniqptr);
```

But this for some reason gives me a C2280 attempting to reference a deleted function.

```
std::sort(teachers.cbegin(), teachers.cend(), compare_by_uniqptr);
```

Here is some context. 'teachers' is a vector of unique pointers of Teacher objects.

```
class Teacher : public Person {
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student>> students;
public:
  Teacher(std::string name) : Person(name) {}
  void insert(std::string name);
  int num_students() { return students.size(); }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Teacher>> teachers;

bool compare_by_uniqptr(const std::unique_ptr<Teacher>& a,
                        const std::unique_ptr<Teacher>& b) 
{
  return a.get()->num_students() > b.get()->num_students();
}
```

I am sorting them by the amount of students each one has in descending order. The begin/end compiles but cbegin/cend does not. Why?

Comment: To sort container you need to modify it, why you are surprised?

Comment: So should I use shared_ptr instead? Why does begin/end work though?

Comment: It uses moves. If it is const, it cannot be moved from. cbegin gives references const objects

Comment: You should use one that has necessary semantic. How cbegin()/cend() is related to unique_ptr vs shared_ptr?

Comment: [Doesn't work with std::vector<int>](https://www.ideone.com/tQhJp3).  And [here is Visual Studio output](http://rextester.com/BYAG65358)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique pointers can not be copied (otherwise they would lose their uniqueness). For that reason when they are sorted, they will need to be *moved* (or *swapped*). Those operations need to change the *internals* of the unique pointers. Of course you can't change the internals of an object through a const reference.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you. So with the way it is written, without const iterators, it will work but is it considered good style? New to this and want to get some ideas

Comment: @pkerts Yes the way it is written is fine. I think, these days, it is more generic to use `std::sort(std::begin(teachers), std::end(teachers), compare_by_uniqptr);` and there is no need in your comparator to call `a.get()->...` on your *unique pointers*, you can just do `a->...`.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) sorts the elements in the range by *moving* them. That means the elements will be modified via the iterator; it won't work with iterator to `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Why `cbegin()` and `cend()` does not work? `std::sort()` as stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) has following type requirements:

> -RandomIt must meet the requirements of ValueSwappable and RandomAccessIterator.
>
> -The type of **dereferenced RandomIt must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable and MoveConstructible**.
>
> -Compare must meet the requirements of Compare.

emphasis is mine. So `std::vector::const_iterator` does not satisfy those requirements. So even if you have `std::vector<int>` and try to use them that would not work either. If you ask why it works on `begin()`/`end()` with `std::unique_ptr` then you can see that in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as well:

> std::swap(std::unique_ptr) (C++11) specializes the std::swap algorithm 
>   (function template)

so `std::unique_ptr` as value satisfies [ValueSwappable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable) concept.

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution. Compatible down to c++11:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

struct Person {
    Person(std::string name);
};

struct Student : Person {

};

class Teacher : public Person {
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student>> students;
public:
  Teacher(std::string name) : Person(name) {}
  void insert(std::string name);
  int num_students() const { return students.size(); }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Teacher>> teachers;

struct by_num_students
{
    bool operator()(Teacher const& l, Teacher const& r) const
    {
        return l.num_students() < r.num_students();
    }
};

template<class Comp>
struct by_pointee_impl
{
    template<class L, class R>
    bool operator()(L&& l, R&& r) const 
    {
        return comp(*l, *r);
    }

    Comp comp;
};
template<class Comp>
auto by_pointee(Comp comp) -> by_pointee_impl<Comp>
{
    return by_pointee_impl<Comp>{comp};
};

int main()
{
    std::sort(begin(teachers), end(teachers), by_pointee(by_num_students()));
}
```